# HTTP version not supported (error 505) - HTTP/1.1^M

Tags: http, tomcat, nginx

In my architecture, there is a Nginx (1.7.4) server as a proxy, delegating requests to Tomcat server.

I noticed that for some requests, for some reason, http version arriving to Tomcat contains weird version: "HTTP/1.1^M". As a result, I getting 505 error - version not supported.

Apparently, it looks like Nginx is the one who doing that - but I not sure.

Any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

UPDATE: from my investigations, it looks like specific kind of GET request causing to the problem (removed sensetive info):

```
 /xxx/xxx/offeringPage/000000?TENANTID=000000000&LWMDSSO_NRM=8eSKtxi106sVrMYuzyROf6JARwtky_5NZdAZDBmBJch6zOdh4dYeYK6uNDT6k-OInD-wWs34LoXWZoxqTM9CjFzSscB-VRnn9vBirHhywLYpna_SFQ66X07PZ4Dm0GHj1AnNRGMQ0tmu2eM4DNgEJAqmLiJLcLX7Dn5gcEeFVPmKEKfi_yhtton8LlP_Qrxv9xKw_SKlmeBnRMexWakWGYHwbIxa2hSRG_3YkODfjrWQlJEEPQHVtICl0NmDYpwldICN_arnjcTiusIZ83nR62mcthLP8XEU8eA8_opfd3_SebfwRzWjxIKxD1VSYqDO8ZL6kMVhj-4cjrtCnRhCBKgKJu2jLrx9vUruOGDczi_dItD6L7epW3GJ3br1Xn8PLCJLbRCJ8qKdipNmxptjwkBNZJYMD8YwMzy1PUNozFtOJAnLdTwSWbFl0pijwUeji-Yq8W2k6vxqCJvF0aohWA9e5FP98NxcihjdWCL_64F_fdvMq8z9uGWw3XPcoiXX4bslwvexPTOYMu9SsPu_WiHnz8HRXwo7EVluK-MvI4mgdIwU2_-ZayymYdIkMcUWrK7sDx7cwLW529Ol7d1xOAhHl_aTjC5cszH0-ikfEP2_rGqpQlzHoJ3F2MArDs-JRFaWO3gas7Ne4bPGoFpoteVkNIU-EtdXz5fXib29DUgV0IY7re1Krn_AiA2QmaxENq5SCV8EjK5Ac67Y1QKdns3Xb6vz3bpqGllq7JGiasaZUX3Mv791xWyC0fPT7NwI43huAyLx-B4OfqtOi8o5p5OD5toGt9ZToRYiVsxz3YD5RQauVAGOXPBklq31x3LFrHpDbtL8p7YLedSptmMSFKoIeFAP7fussz7xzgKlpApsW3ZJ4etiKiEld6Wl6SMu-bPWaXjnJRFrr7GZ6WuoZuG0mzLopXGsIMtTGpTblloUQeCIwSC9LW81uOVj1akOIPH6aIq0MQTiGBbucQhNB0i84xx2o0PXGO6QfdTLsGceCTVxGqD8qUGcSfd8ySzeU0Nfc3xf3KEm-ztWn-FvGqXI8mIiGBuPqKOMWE__wc8NPHI1jeXMkG8mNl-WwzV0IuMfDNeDUcElmdT0yTH__9_r07__g43pNwDH7_m3XlIOLyDijHkNj5qwK-aNN9aNU6ZgK7924TuDLdg3yLrH_vatREeyYOZyxj7v58TJgvYoNYB-enma7jB2ofSleb0vnoc_zTI9AeRM9TQ9ssGNiZaa13FHo_gpLMDnyemagmRvcoX3asOEmcQ2leFQuFnKgIqD6DEjCHE1xKOoWGXrzdv8-y8Al1bTpU9CYc_l8d4.&idpId=http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xx/xxxx/services/trust
```

Another thing: the problem is not consistent. With exactly same request, it reproducing about 3/5 of time.

UPDATE2: I found [this](https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http/issues/60) post, which looks very familiar to my problem. Is this documented Nginx behavior?

UPDATE3: found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it) site - looks like ^M is a carriage-return character. Why this character may be created?

Comment: What does your proxy config look like? Are you specifying the version anywhere?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence: my config is very complex, in some of the locations I do specify http version. For example: proxy_http_version 1.1

Comment: @KeenanLawrence: I updated my question with more info

Comment: Have you tried updating your nginx to actual and supported version?

Comment: I see. Is it specified in the location that's delegating requests to Tomcat?

Comment: @VBart: Sounds trivial, but unfortunately is not. We are a quite large organization and Nginx upgrade is a process that will take months for get approval and to perform all the required testing... At least I need a proove that the problem is in this specific Nginx version.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence: Every request (except static files) is delegated to Tomcat. Some of locations have http version specified, some other doesn't (I don't know why, that was done years ago). I don't know which of the locations handles "problematic" request (I going to figure out)

Comment: The post by link isn't related to your problem at all. Note, that `^M`, which looks like "carriage return" symbol is absolutely normal and goes right after the version by HTTP protocol specification. The post by the link is about invalid host header.

Comment: Check the HTTP request syntax in the spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.1

Comment: @VBart: but.. if this character passed to Tomcat, can it "recognize" it as string (e.g., literally "^M") and cause to "wrong version" error?

Comment: `^M` is likely just a representation of it in log files.

Comment: @VBart: I debugging on Window machine. I just examined Tomcat logs using hex editor. What I see, is that only "error 505" request have the following http version string: HTTP/1.1.     In hex editor, it is: 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 0D

Comment: Tomcat escapes control symbols and writes it in log in this format to avoid breaking log file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121162/discussion-between-illidan-and-vbart).